# very high current buck converter

Tags: buck, converter, current-limiting

Need to convert 40 volts to a 24 volt 2000 amp 1 second duration pulse. long duty cycle. Current must be settable from 500 to 2000 amps and time from 0.1 to 1.0 seconds. Ideas please.

Comment: Many interleaved buck converters.

Comment: What he said, assuming that your input 40v power supply has the ooomph to drive the converter. Build or buy one 50A current-output converter to run your tests and develop the controls, then parallel a bunch of them.

Comment: And how much can the current vary during the length of the pulse? Please also state what power supply you will be using to generate the 40 volt supply? What duty cycle is needed i.e. how often do you need to repeat a pulse? Please don't make guesses here because you'll just be wasting people's time.

Comment: ~ 50 kW. Heavy metal. It would probably help to provide more details re the load and overall system. On such a substantial system its very easy for simple answers to not work for complex reasons affected by the sheer magnitude of current involved.  
What draws 2000A ?

Comment: An answer for a 2000A spot welder is going to be different from a 2000A pulsed laser diode driver, both might require the same voltage and current, but both have quite different design criteria so we're all going to need to know just a little more about what it is you have in mind here.

Comment: The 40 volts is a very solid battery supply capable of delivering more than 2000 amps. Current should be the same during the pulse, Duty cycle is off for 40 seconds. The load is a short arc. During the pulse the current cannot drop below 50 amps. so a PWM output would be Ok. Would a chip like the LT1339 work in this and just scaling up all the components for the current. The idea of paralleling is being considered and will be necessary for the output switches ( MOSFETs?) .

Comment: So the output voltage *is* permitted to vary, in order to limit the current? And how much ripple is permitted? And by the way, simply switching 2,000 Amps in 1 microsecond will magnetically-trash all the control circuits. This example is from an electric-train speed controller---it had 2,000 amps in 1uS, only 4cm from the speed controller of IGBTs. Devices were failing on the PCB, because of Hfield changes. I computed 80 volts upset induced into GND plane. The consultant complained about the risk of inserting a thick shield plate. I offerd "Even gutta percha will work. Try the plate,"

Comment: Our idea is to use 200 amp modules and parallel outputs. Ripple can be 10 volts. Mosfets seem to.look most promising. Massive ground plane yes!!